# "Ring" tactic in CoqIde not accepted

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I am learning Coq and I need to use, for the first time, the `ring` tactic. I have tried using it after `Require Ring.` or `Require ArithRing.` to simplify the right side of an equation that I have as a goal, but Coq takes it a reference that does not exist. I copy my piece of code here (I have tried several times with `ring` and `ring_simplify`):

```
Lemma sum_n_p : forall n, 2 * sum_n n + n = n * n.

(* sum_n n is inductively defined as the sum of all numbers between 1 and n *)

Proof.
intros n.
induction n as [ |m IHm].
+simpl.
reflexivity.
+assert (SnSn : S m * S m = m * m + 2 * m + 1).
ring_simplify in [S m * S m = m * m + 2 * m + 1]. (*or just ring. , neither works*)
rewrite SnSn.
rewrite <- IHm.
simpl.
ring.
Qed.
```

Comment: Just a small tip for next time: try to provide a complete working example, so that it is easier for us to help you. (You did not include the definition of `sum_n`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call those tactics, you need to import those modules, not just require them:

```
Require Import ArithRing Ring.
```

I tried running your proof after adding those lines, but Coq got stuck in a different error. You might still need to adjust your script before it gets accepted by Coq.

Comment: Yes, there are some more problems, but my major problem is solved, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Lyuben If the answer resolved your issue then a nice thing to do would be to mark it as accepted.

Comment: [`Coq.Arith.Arith`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Arith.Arith.html) exports `ArithRing` and the latter exports `Ring`, so `Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.` would also work.

Comment: @Lyuben My pleasure! Thank you for making SO a better place!